# How can i make a 2D array with existing lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, 2d

for instance, i have a txt data called 'mazeline' like this:

```
abcd
cdae
korp
```

So i first made 3 lists:

```
mazeline = readmaze.split()
mline0 =  list(mazeline[0])
mline1 =  list(mazeline[1])
mline2 =  list(mazeline[2])
```

So the 3 lists are:

```
mline0 = [a,b,c,d]
mline1 = [c,d,a,e]
mline2 = [k,o,r,p]
```

and i want to make a 2D array like this:

```
[[a,b,c,d],[c,d,a,e],[k,o,r,p]]
```

or is there any way that i can make a 2d array directly from the first data?

any suggestions? any help would be good.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the lists inside another list

```
res = [mline0, mline1, mline2]
```

more simply, you can skip the intermediate variables and use a list comprehension

```
res = [list(mline) for mline in readmaze.split()]
```

Comment: i think it's my mistake, but the type of the result is still a list. can't i change it to an array?

Comment: In python there's no really a need for something like 'arrays', we just use nested lists. (If you **really** need arrays, numpy has some)

Comment: thanks 
but i don't want [['a','b','c','d'], ...., 'p']]
i want
[[a,b,c,d],[c,d,a,e],[k,o,r,p]]
what should i do?

Comment: The contents of a text file are strings so the output is [['a','b','c','d'], ...., 'p']] to denote that 'a', 'b', ... are strings. Perhaps what you really want to ask is how to convert the contents of the nested array/list into some Python type such as int?

Comment: @H.Choi, sorry not sure what you mean. The a,b,c,d have to be objects of some kind. If they are not strings, what should they be? Perhaps it will help if you can describe what you need the this for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this list comprehension:

```
[[int(i) for i in line.strip()] for line in open('file/path')]
```