# how can i make a 2d array out of a text file?

Tags: python, arrays, text, 2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i make a 2D array with existing lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768862/how-can-i-make-a-2d-array-with-existing-lists)

I have a text file 'mapview.txt' and its content is:

```
1234
5678
9012
```

i want the result to be:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,0,1,2,]]
```

i don't want such as:

```
[['1','2','3','4'],['5','6','7','8'],['9','0','1','2']]
```

i have a code like this:

```
getit = open('./mapview.txt')
readit = getit.read()

itsline = readit.split()
line0 = list(itsline[0])
line1 = list(itsline[1])
line2 = list(itsline[2])

final = [line0,line1,line2]

print final
```

but the result is

```
[['1','2','3','4'],['5','6','7','8'],['9','0','1','2']]
```

how can i get

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,0,1,2,]]
```

? i need that form since i'll use the integers in the array.

any suggestions? any help would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can change all the strings in a list to ints with:

```
map(int, lst)
```

(The `map` function applies a function to every item of a list, and the `int` function turns a string into a list). In your case, you need to change all the strings in a *list of lists*, so you would want something like

```
[map(int, lst) for lst in final]
```

One other thing to note about your code is that

```
line0 = list(itsline[0])
line1 = list(itsline[1])
line2 = list(itsline[2])
```

Is not a good idea- it works only if there are exactly 3 lines in your file. This could also be improved with:

```
final = map(list, itsline)
```

Answer (score 2):

To amend your solution, change

```
line0 = list(itsline[0])
line1 = list(itsline[1])
line2 = list(itsline[2])
```

to

```
line0 = [int(i) for i in itsline[0]]
line1 = [int(i) for i in itsline[1]]
line2 = [int(i) for i in itsline[2]]
```

But this list comprehension will be more efficient:

```
[[int(i) for i in line.strip()] for line in open('file/path')]
```

Comment: `open().strip` won't work. You might mean [line.strip()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12769786/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: you're right. Bug fixed

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('./mapview.txt') as file:
     array2d = [[int(digit) for digit in line.strip()] for line in file]

print(array2d)
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/y3EA6)

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 0, 1, 2]]
```